# Using strtotime to format date() with AM/PM

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have this line of code I wrote to create a formatted timestamp on emails from my contact us page.

It is working fine, but I'm wondering if it is written poorly and could be reduced into more efficient code?  It feels wrong calling date() three times in one line.  I'm not a developer by trade.

```
$timestamp = date('m-d-Y')." ".date('h:i A', strtotime(date('H:i:s')));
```

which results in: `05-28-2014 03:49 PM`

Thoughts?

Comment: `$timestamp = date('m-d-Y h:i A');`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need the current timestamp, you can use,

```
$timestamp=date("m-d-Y h:i A");
```

When you need to format the timestamp you fetched from database or other means, you have to use `strtotime`.

```
$format_timestamp=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($timestamp)); // I just convert your format to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format.
```

Edit:

When you need to subtract x hours from the current time, use

```
$timestamp=date("m-d-Y h:i A", strtotime("-4 hour"));
```

Some more examples,

```
$timestamp=date("m-d-Y h:i A", strtotime("+2 hour")); // Adds 2 hours
$timestamp=date("m-d-Y h:i A", strtotime("+1 day")); // Adds 1 Day
```

Comment: It seems I left out some valuable information in my original question:

My actual code is as follows:
    $timestamp = date('m-d-Y')." ".date('h:i A', strtotime(date('H:i:s')) - 60*60*4);

which subtracts 4 hours from the time(timezone conversion) before formatting.  How would you make this better?  
Thanks.

Comment: @user3685142 for time zone you do not have to do manual conversion, you can take a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php#109321

Comment: Thank you for your answer(s).  By the way, I had to put quotes around -4 hour to make it work IE: strtotime("-4 hour")

Comment: @user3685142: That was a careless mistake. Corrected though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify making:

```
$timestamp = date('m-d-Y h:i A');
```

or

```
$timestamp = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s");
```

For more information, see:

PHP Manual

date http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

gmdate http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php